# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wittgenstein'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I would like to use the Ripper algorithm but I am unable to `import wittgenstein`
The installation was successful but I cannot import it in spyder. I am using python 3.8 and pip 20.2

Comment: by any chance do you have more than one python installation? check for which one it was installed and which one you use in spyder

Comment: yes, I was using python 3.7.7 in spyder. I upgraded it to python 3.8.5 now I am getting an error when running my file. ImportError: cannot import name 'var' from 'numpy' (unknown location). Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: please, edit your question to include all relevant information - your code, full traceback, etc. or even better - ask new question

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command in terminal

```
pip install wittgenstein
```

Comment: OP states "I am using python 3.8 and pip 20.2" .. so it's installed. Don't see how this can solve the issue